# Refactor Two JS Functions That Share Same Variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring, dry

What would be the best way to refactor the following two functions that include very similar variable declarations:

```
function minFeeCheck(input) {
    input.value = parseFloat(input.value).toFixed(2);
    var minFeeUpdate = parseFloat($("#minimumFee").val()).toFixed(2);
    var maxFeeUpdate = parseFloat($("#maximumFee").val()).toFixed(2);
    var minInt = parseInt(minFeeUpdate);
    var maxInt = parseInt(maxFeeUpdate);
       if (minFeeUpdate < 0) input.value = 0;
       if (minInt > maxInt) input.value = maxFeeUpdate;
       if (minInt > maxInt) {
           input.value = minFeeUpdate;
           $("#maximumFee").val(minFeeUpdate);
       }
}
function maxFeeCheck(input) {
    input.value = parseFloat(input.value).toFixed(2);
    var minFeeUpdate = parseFloat($("#minimumFee").val()).toFixed(2);
    var maxFeeUpdate = parseFloat($("#maximumFee").val()).toFixed(2);
    var minInt = parseInt(minFeeUpdate);
    var maxInt = parseInt(maxFeeUpdate);
       if (maxFeeUpdate < 0) input.value = 0;
       if (maxInt < minInt) {
           input.value = maxFeeUpdate;
           $("#minimumFee").val(maxFeeUpdate);
       }
}
```

Both functions seem to be similar except one target a minimum and one targets a maximum.  What would be the most ideal and cleanest method of writing this out while maintaining the same functionality.  Thanks.

**UPDATE**

With the help of @gaetanoM, here is a possible solution.  It includes a check if the user enters a negative number (which would change the minFee and maxFee as a zero).

HTML:

```
<input id="minFee" class="form-control form-control-custom" value="" maxlength="255" onchange="minMaxFeeCheck(this);" min="0" max="200" data-toggle="tooltip" title="A number greater than zero and less than maximum fee." type="number"/>

<input id="maxFee" class="form-control form-control-custom" value="" maxlength="255" onchange="minMaxFeeCheck(this);" min="0" max="200" data-toggle="tooltip" title="A number greater than zero and minimum fee." type="number"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
function minMaxFeeCheck(input, minormax) {
    input.value = parseFloat(input.value).toFixed(2);
    var minFeeUpdate = parseFloat($("#minimumFee").val()).toFixed(2);
    var maxFeeUpdate = parseFloat($("#maximumFee").val()).toFixed(2);
    var minInt = parseInt(minFeeUpdate);
    var maxInt = parseInt(maxFeeUpdate);
    var tmp = (minormax) ? minFeeUpdate : maxFeeUpdate;
    if (input.value < 0) {
          input.value = 0;
          $("#minimumFee").val(0);
    } else {
        if (tmp < 0) input.value = 0;
        if (minInt > maxInt) input.value = tmp;
        if (minInt > maxInt) {
            input.value = tmp;
            $("#minimumFee").val(tmp);
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposal is:

```js
function minmaxFeeCheck(input, minormax) {
    input.value = parseFloat(input.value).toFixed(2);
    var minFeeUpdate = parseFloat($("#minimumFee").val()).toFixed(2);
    var maxFeeUpdate = parseFloat($("#maximumFee").val()).toFixed(2);
    var minInt = parseInt(minFeeUpdate);
    var maxInt = parseInt(maxFeeUpdate);

    var tmp = (minormax) ? minFeeUpdate : maxFeeUpdate;

    if (tmp < 0) input.value = 0;
    if (minInt > maxInt) input.value = tmp;
    if (minInt > maxInt) {
        input.value = tmp;
        $("#minimumFee").val(tmp);
    }
}
```

Indeed:

```
if (minInt > maxInt) {
```

is the same of:

```
if (maxInt < minInt) {
```

Comment: I like this solution a lot.  The only exception is that it allows negative numbers in the minimum input.  I don't think a negative dollar amount should be allowed. Thanks for your idea.

Comment: @PeteAdamBialecki you can apply the **Math.abs(...your number...)** in order to get the absolute value....

Comment: I think the Math.abs() route would be good but perhaps forcing any negative numbers to change to zero would be the best route.  I'll update my question with your suggestions.  Let me know what you think.

Comment: @PeteAdamBialecki  I read your update. It's excellent way to solve negative values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method :

```
 function minMaxFeeCheck(input) {
  input.value = +parseFloat(input.value).toFixed(2);
  const minFeeUpdate = +parseFloat($("#minimumFee").val()).toFixed(2);
  const maxFeeUpdate = +parseFloat($("#maximumFee").val()).toFixed(2);
  minFeeUpdate < 0 ? input.value = 0 : minFeeUpdate > maxFeeUpdate ? input.value = minFeeUpdate && $('#maximumFee').val(minFeeUpdate) : input.value = maxFeeUpdate && $('#minimumFee').val(maxFeeUpdate);
}
```